# How to send a post request authentication with specific variables for username and password?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to send a POST request authentication using `auth` with `companyId` and `accountPassword`variables but it fails to authenticate if I use the `auth` way

Following works but I cannot use the username and password in URL as its creating security issues with the username and password stored in logs

```
url = AUTH_URI + '/' + dyn_url + "?appIdKey=" + str.encode(APP_ID_KEY) + "&companyId=" + self._user + "&accountPassword=" + self._pswd
                r2 = requests.post(url,timeout=DEFAULT_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'},allow_redirects=False)
```

Changing it to use auth variable fails to authenticate,any guidance on how to fix this?

```
            url = AUTH_URI + '/' + dyn_url + "?appIdKey=" + str.encode(APP_ID_KEY)
            r2 = requests.post(url,timeout=DEFAULT_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'},auth=('companyId=self._user','accountPassword=self._pswd'),allow_redirects=False)
```

I get the following error,somehow the `'companyId=self._user','accountPassword=self._pswd'` not taking affect

Error:-

```
Please enter the username and password
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the string literal `'self._user'` as the username. Try using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) if you are running Python 3.6 or above:

```
r2 = requests.post(url,
    timeout=DEFAULT_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'},
    auth=(f'companyId={self._user}',
          f'accountPassword={self._pswd}'),
    allow_redirects=False)
```

Edit: For Python 2.7 it would be:

```
r2 = requests.post(url,
    timeout=DEFAULT_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'},
    auth=('companyId={}'.format(self._user),
          'accountPassword={}'.format(self._pswd)),
    allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: I still get `Please enter your Company ID and password`,I am doing it in python 2.7, just replaced the `f` with `r`

Comment: Please tag your questions properly, especially if you are using an end-of-life'd Python version. For Python 2 that would be `'companyId={}'.format(self._user)`. `r""` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: actually , resolved it as `r1 = requests.post(url1, timeout=1000, allow_redirects=False, data={'companyId': username, 'accountPassword': password})`,that will form-encode data for you and use it as the post body

Comment: Ok, great. I was assuming that you were trying to use HTTP Basic Authentication.